# Unable to Start an Activity From NavDrawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am using a navigation drawer in my application. From the navDrawer fragment I want to open one activity , And I want to show a listview in that activity I tried to add these two intent to start my activity and I also added my new CustomListView activity in manifest file, but it doesn't works,

```
Intent openList = new Intent(getActivity(), CustomListView.class);
            PrincipalSpeechFragment.this.startActivity(openList);

Intent openList = new Intent(getActivity(), CustomListView.class);
            startActivity(openList);
```

And the app is unfortunately getting closed. Can anyone tell me a solution for this?

Logcat Errors are:

```
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979): Process: com.example.everwinvidhyashram, PID: 17979
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at    com.example.everwinvidhyashram.PrincipalSpeechFragment$1.onClick(PrincipalSpeechFragment.java:59)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-13 01:49:19.391: E/AndroidRuntime(17979):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the error? can You post the activity holding the fragment?

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein I added my logcat errors.

Comment: what is the activity type ( extension ) that holds the fragment?

Comment: Speech extends Fragment... And the activity extends Activity...

Comment: where is exactly is the "com.example.everwinvidhyashram.PrincipalSpeechFragment$1.onClick(PrincipalSpeechFragment.java:59)" , on what row?